# How to get difference properties of object in c#?

Tags: c#

i have a class with some properties like this:

```
public class Car 
    {
        public long No { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Door { get; set; }
        public Color Color { get; set; }
        public int MaxSpeed { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
    }
```

*(this class is an example, my real class is very bigger than it.)*

In my program, I need to get difference properties of this class from db(not all properties each time). For example in one case I need **name** and **color** of some cars, and in other case I need **name** and **door** and **price**.
I want to create **one** method that support all difference conditions. I know that i could create it using **‘params’** and **‘enum’**, but I am research about best way to do it. Thanks

Comment: I assume _"get difference properties"_ actually means _"get different properties"_, am i right? Apart from that, your question is not clear at all. If the `Car` is initialized properly, what hinders you to use the property that you need?

Comment: Did you use Entity Framework to get data from db or another LINQ compatible ORM?

Comment: Unless some properties are particularly expensive to get (e.g. because they come from a different table) you would be better off returning the entire `Car` all the time. The biggest time sink in going to the DB is a round-trip; once you get one column, the cost of adding ten more columns is very small.

Comment: The simple answer is: don't. Just load the `Car` object and use what properties you need. None of them look expensive to load so it'll be fine, and any gains in performance (there won't be any) would be massively outweighed by code complexity.

Comment: Agree with  dasblinkenlight. Also, if your class is *very* much bigger, maybe consider if that one class doing too much?

Comment: If you're using LINQ to a database (EF or L2S) then you could write a projection to an anonymous object (e.g. `db.Cars.Select(c => new {c.No, c.Name});`) but depending how you use it you could end up hitting the db multiple times and having the opposite problem. You're almost certainly okay to just load the Car and all it's properties.

Comment: I think retreiving the whole row. shouldn't be a problem, but if you want te retreive partial rows, You could create serveral classes. CarWithColor. Or create some interfaces. But that could give some other problems. Thats the battle of `typed vs untyped`

Comment: as Jeroen van Langen mentioned,i also think making a basecar class with base properities and for specific properties to  child classes like carwithcolor:basecar should be more programatic design..

Answer (score 0):

You can just query the propertie when it is called.

```
public int Value{
      get{
         int myValue = getValue();
         return myValue;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try do this way:

```
public object[] GetProperties(int state)
{
 object[] temp;
 switch(state)
 {
    case(0):
    {
        temp=new object[]{Name,Color};
    }break;
    case(1):
    {
        temp=new object[]{Name,door};
    }
 }
}
```

After that, you know , what need return your function, and it's easy parse return result!